# Javascript File Reader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I may just not be understanding the file reader api, but

When I try to run:

```
for (var i = 0, f1, f2; f1 = files[sorted_index[i]], f2 = files[sorted_index[i+1]]; i=i+2) {
    var file_one;
    var file_two;

    if(f1.size < f2.size){
        file_one = f1;
        file_two = f2;
    } else {
        file_one = f2;
        file_two = f1;
    }

    var file_one_contents;
    var file_two_contents;


  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file_one);
  reader.onload = readSuccess;

  function readSuccess(evt){
    file_one_contents = evt.target.result;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file_two);
    reader.onload = readSuccess2;

  function readSuccess2(evt2){
    file_two_contents = evt2.target.result;
  }

    console.log(file_one_contents);
    console.log(file_two_contents);
```

The console log only contains *undefined* in it.
The goal of the script it two read in two CSVs and take the data from the pair of files and do some computations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API is **asynchronous**. The "success" functions are called when the operation completes, and that won't be immediate.

Move your `console.log()` calls to **inside** the handler functions.

*edit* — If you need to wait to start doing stuff until both files are ready, you can do something like this:

```
  var countdown = 2;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file_one);
  reader.onload = readSuccess;

  function readSuccess(evt){
    file_one_contents = evt.target.result;
    countdown--;
    if (countdown === 0) go();
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file_two);
    reader.onload = readSuccess2;

  function readSuccess2(evt2){
    file_two_contents = evt2.target.result;
    countdown--;
    if (countdown === 0) go();
  }
```

There are more sophisticated ways to do it, of course, but that simple trick just waits until the counter is zero before calling "go()", which represents the function that'd work on processing the files.

Comment: so how do I make it wait for the file to be uploaded before I start manipulating it?

Comment: Right, so is there no way to pass the information out of the handler functions to be used later?

Comment: @StevenStangle With your current approach you need an `Array` of `FileReader`s.

Comment: @StevenStangle no, there isn't.  Just call the functions that process the files from within those callbacks.

Comment: @Pointy but the files are linked together, you need both together to do the processing. So is it never possible to use both at once?

Comment: @StevenStangle I'll update my answer with a way to deal with that.

Comment: @Pointy okay, that makes sense, but now it is only outputting the first pair of files. The final script would have to work for many pairs of files. Any ideas?

Comment: @StevenStangle The event listener of one `FileReader` can define and run a second one. Watch out for closures.

Comment: @StevenStangle as PointerEars says, you'd have to take the basic idea and build upon it.  If you've got a list of files, you need to start the counter off at the list length.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem which solved the file read waiting by using ".onloadend" instead of "onload". In the code below x is bound to a "div" element

```
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    x.innerHTML = evt.target.result;
}
```

With "onload" it was all undefined.